# Extension host terminated unexpectedly while debugging React-native project

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, react-native-debugger, react-native-tools

[Developer console when the error occurs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o3AO.jpg)

Any methods without disabling react-native-tool extension?

Answer (score 0):

You give only very few Information... ...but I give it a try:

It's seems you use vscode, and the flow-Plugin is the cause of the issue.
So please uninstall (or disable) `vscode-flow-ide` and install `Flow Language Support` instead.

If this helps, don't miss to vote up for my answer, if not, describe in detail, what you've try and what's happend.

good luck